# C++ - Precompiled headers issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, precompiled-headers

Okay so I am writing something up in C++ and last night it was fine, I could compile perfectly w/o a problem. I saved all of my stuff and closed VS 2010 Ultimate. This morning when I went to go work on my stuff I tried recompiling and I got just over 200 errors, I couldn't figure out why so I noticed there were a few more warnings than usual and it says that it is skipping my headers.

```
Warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use.
```

I tried disabling precompiled headers for my main .cpp but when I compile it just gives me even more errors. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the code of main.cpp?

Comment: Add  #include "stdafx.h" at the the top of your cpp file, just above other include directives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting on my magic telepathic helmet, you problem is:

Your `#include "myPrecompiledHeader.h"` is not the first include in a file, when it should be.

Comment: I sense that the name of the precompiled header is... stdafx.h.

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted more information, though the warning says it skipped `#include<iostream>` because preprocessor was expecting a precompiled header file.
In case of your Visual C++ project that file normally is stdafx.h, try adding it as,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Add #include "stadfax.h" at the the top of your cpp file, just above other include directives.

Comment: Why doesn't disabling precompiled headers fix the problem?

Comment: I think visual studio manages pre-compiled headers not by project but by files. So OP probably will have to disable it for all files.